# How do I test file input for int?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a program that reads integers from a file and assigns them to certain variables. I have this block of code below to error check the information that is coming from the file. If the information is not a positive integer, the if statement is supposed to catch it and reset the variable and io stream.

```
int quantity;
input >> quantity;
if(input.fail() || (quantity < 0)){
   quantity = 0; 
   input.clear();
   input.ignore(200, ' ');
}
```

However, if the information is a double, then it doesn't enter this block of code and the rest of my program stops working properly. How do I get my program to enter the if statement when a double shows up in my file?

Comment: Please provide a complete [mre]

Comment: When you talk about reset I/O stream are you talking about the state of the I/O stream or the read position?

Comment: You should read the number as a string variable, then parse it for an acceptable format.  For example, having a decimal point may indicate the number is floating point.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews If I read the number as a string, then parse it for an acceptable format, how would I turn that number into an int variable? Edit: I just looked it up I think you have to use string stream?

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ. The linked answer has nothing to do with the question. It is not a duplicate. You should at least read the question and try to understand it

Comment: The answer is: The extracor operator will extract characters, until it hits a character  that cannot be converted to the requested type. Example: input contains "12.34". Then the extractor can read 12 and convert this to an integer. So, no failure. You will find still ".34" in the stream.